# uncountable mutually singular continuous measure on $R$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I am trying to find example of an uncountable collection of mutually singular continuous measure on $R$. Does there exist such a collection on $R$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is yes, here is an explicit example.

Let $B=\{0,1\}^\mathbb N$ and $u:B\to\mathbb R$ defined by $u(b)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{+\infty}2^{-n}b_n$ for every $b=(b_n)_{n\geqslant1}$ in $B$. For $p$ in $(0,1)$, let $\mu_p$ denote the measure on $B$ which is the product of the measures $p\delta_1+(1-p)\delta_0$. The measures $\mu_p$ are mutually singular hence their images $\nu_p$ by $u$ are mutually singular probability measures on $\mathbb R$. Each $\nu_p$ is atomless. Finally $\nu_{1/2}$ is the Lebesgue measure restricted to $[0,1]$.

Comment: I have few doubts. you have written product of measures. can you explain me product of which measures? then what is the meaning of image of a measure under a map? thanks

Comment: Product of the Bernoulli probability measures $p\delta_1+(1-p)\delta_0$, as written in the post. // The image of a measure $\mu$ on $(E,\mathcal E)$ by a measurable function $u:(E,\mathcal E)\to(F,\mathcal F)$ is the measure $\nu$ on $(F,\mathcal F)$defined by $\nu(A)=\mu(u^{-1}(A))$ for every $A$ in $\mathcal F$.

Comment: @Did, can you explain why the measures $\mu_p$ are mutually singular?

Comment: @jennifer Law of large numbers.